# $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues and $AB=BA$ with $AC=CA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Suppose $A,B$ and $C$ are three matrices $n\times n$ matrices such that $A$
has $n$ distinct eigenvalues. Suppose $AB=BA$ and $AC=CA$ then prove that $BC=CB$..

Suppose $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues. So, $A$ is diagonalizable.

Consider the special case when $A$ itself is diagonal.. As $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues we assume no two diagonal elements of $A$ are same.

Suppose $B=(b_{ij})$ and $AB=BA$..

Let $AB=(c_{ij})$ with $c_{ij}=\sum a_{ik}b_{kj}=a_{ii}b_{ij}$

Let $BA=(d_{ij})$  with $d_{ij}=\sum b_{ik}a_{kj}=b_{ij}a_{jj}$

As $AB=BA$ we have $c_{ij}=d_{ij}$ for all $i,j$ i.e., $a_{ii}b_{ij}=b_{ij}a_{jj}$ for all $i,j$..

We then have $(a_{ii}-a_{jj})b_{ij}=0$. As no two diagonal elements in $A$ are equal we have $a_{ii}-a_{jj}\neq 0$ for $i\neq j$ so, $b_{ij}=0$ for $i\neq j$. Thus $B$ is a diagonal matrix.. Similarly, $C$ is also a diagonal matrix.

Clearly, any two diagonal matrices commute.. So, $BC=CB$..

Now, I do not know how to consider general case when $A$ is not a diagonal matrix but have $n$ distinct eigenvalues..

Please give only hints..

Comment: Notice that $A$ is diagonalizable. What can you do?

Comment: I can find a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $PDP^{-1}=A$.. I have tried in that order also.. could not succeed.. @SangchulLee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diagonalizing $A$ means that we are choosing some nice basis on $\Bbb{R}^n$ with respect to which the matrix representation of $A$ is diagonal. Then your proof carries out and the conclusion follows.

In other words, choose $P$ such that $A = PDP^{-1}$ for some diagonal matrix $D$. (Of course, no two diagonal elements of $D$ are equal since they are eigenvalues of $A$.) Let $\tilde{B} = P^{-1}BP$ and $\tilde{C} = P^{-1}CP$ so that $\tilde{B}D = D\tilde{B}$ and $\tilde{C}D = D\tilde{C}$. Your computation shows that $\tilde{B}\tilde{C} = \tilde{C}\tilde{B}$. This implies $BC = CB$.

Comment: And you can assume no two diagonal elements in $D$ ares same as $A$ has distinct eigenvalues

Comment: How do you know that B and C are diagonalizable ?

Comment: @Med, We don't know that at first, though cello's computation shows that indeed $A, B, C$ are simultaneously diagonalizable. Anyway we are *not* diagonalizing $B$ and $C$ here. We are just taking [similarity transform](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity).

Comment: @SangchulLee, Is (B~) a digonal matrix? we do not know if such a similarity transform exists without knowing that B is diagonalizable. I am just asking this because you mentioned that you have not assumed B and C to be diagonalizable.

Comment: @Med, I am not assuming anything about $B$ and $C$, except for commuting condition. So $\tilde{B}$ and $\tilde{C}$ are also just matrices. I guess you are confused since I am not explaining what $P$ is here. This was originally part of the comment... So sorry about that. Hope this edit will make things clear.

Comment: @SangchulLee, it is clear now. Thank you.